# Maintain order when selecting values jquery

Tags: jquery

Is there any functionality on the roadmap that will, when selecting values from the select, maintain order in the created list based on the order
  Basically, if the initial multiple select looks like this:

```
1. Option 1
2. Option 2
3. Option 3
4. Option 4

Then, if from the list, I select options in this order: 3, 1, 4, 2
The value pass should look like this:
Option 1 
Option 2 
Option 3 
Option 4
```

any idea to maintain selected order of multi select

Comment: What will be the criteria for this your intended order? Alphabetical? Numerical?  What is the criteria?

Comment: ur question is unclear

Comment: if i select this order 3, 1, 4, 2 , i want to pass data like this order 3, 1, 4, 2 . not an 1,2,3,4

Comment: I think I understand the question (OP, correct me if I'm wrong). He wants to **preserve the order in which the elements were selected**, not order the elements programmatically. But as far as I know, this isn't how multiselect boxes work.

Comment: hi Flater u are correct , i wants to preserve the order in which the elements were i selected, not order the elements programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
<select multiple>
  <option value="1">first</option>
  <option value="2">second</option>
  <option value="3">third</option>
  <option value="4">fourth</option>
</select>

$('select').on('change', function() {
  var orderedValues = $(this).val();
});
```